# How do I achieve this chapter optic?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, xetex, miktex, document-classes

I'd like to modify the chapter appearance to become similar to  this draft:

[image]

I use XeLaTeX and Minion Pro/Myriad Pro (from Adobe Reader) as main fonts (the sans font in the screenshot might be a different type).
Are there any package I could use, and does that imply a specific document class?

I need to have DINA4 and thought of KOMAscript (`scrbook`), but found that `memoir` might have better section styling abilities...
However, I've got no idea where to start.

**Update:** It seems to work now. Does anybody know if the *fncychap* package could be used to draw something like this (with a full sidewidth line): [image: second]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to use this style, you can use the `Lenny` style from the `fncychap` package and make some adjustments; for example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ChNameVar{\fontsize{14}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{60}{62}\selectfont\color{gray}}
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `lmodern` package was only used because it admits the font sizes used. In your actual document you might need to make some adjustments to the font attributes and use fonts which admit them. In the example I used the `book` document class, but this will also work with `memoir`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed "\color" by "\textcolor" and it did look like intended.